# My Keras yolov3-tiny.h5 model has an input tensor with dimensions ?,?,?,3 while I would expect ?,416,416,3

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When inspecting the Keras model yolov3-tiny.h5 using netron

I see that the input node is called input_1  and has type float32[?,?,?,3]. I would expect float32[?,416,416,3]

How can I force it to be float32[?,416,416,3]?
This is needed for downstream processing. The Keras model has to be converted to a frozen_model.pb in Tensorflow and then be further processed for deployement.
The deployement tools cannot handle an input with unknow w,h size.

Here is how I generated the Keras model. I downloaded the yolov3-tiny.cfg (https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov3-tiny.cfg) and yolov3-tiny.weigths (https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3-tiny.weights)

And then converted the model to a keras model using the following command :

python convert.py -p yolov3-tiny.cfg yolov3-tiny.weights model_data/yolov3-tiny.h5

(this code is obtained by cloning https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3)

Making a prediction using the saved Keras model works fine :
python yolo_video.py --image --model model_data/yolov3-tiny.h5

However when inspecting the Keras model yolov3-tiny.h5 using netron

I see that the input node is called input_1  and has type float32[?,?,?,3]

I would expect float32[?,416,416,3]

How can I force it to be float32[?,416,416,3]?

Comment: Thats interesting. The only thing I can think of is the model does not know what the input shape should be. Did you define the input shape in the keras model? Can you load the model and then print the summary and see what that give

Answer (score 0):

You could do that while converting the keras model file to tflite by passing input_shapes as a dictionary with input node name as the key and shape as the value.
Check out the TFLiteConverter class [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c4a9de96742d85a8772e3868fc2f13955a195e18/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py#L1509)

```
    def _main_(args):
        kmodel = args.kmodel
        lmodel = args.lmodel
        converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(kmodel, input_shapes={"input_1":[1,416,416,3]})
        converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
        tflite_model = converter.convert()
        open("lmodel", "wb").write(tflite_model)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Quantize a trained yolo model')
        argparser.add_argument('-k', '--kmodel', help='path to model weights file input')
        argparser.add_argument('-l', '--lmodel', help='path to tensor flow lite output')
        args = argparser.parse_args()
        _main_(args)
```